# Eliminating redundant function calls in comprehensions from within the comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say we need a program which takes a list of strings and splits them, and appends the first two words, in a tuple, to a list and returns that list; in other words, a program which gives you the first two words of each string.

```
input: ["hello world how are you", "foo bar baz"]
output: [("hello", "world"), ("foo", "bar")]
```

It can be written like so (we assume valid input):

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    result = []
    for s in strings:
        splt = s.split()
        result.append((splt[0], splt[1]))
    return result
```

But a list comprehension would be much nicer.

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    return [(s.split()[0], s.split()[1]) for s in strings]
```

But this involves two calls to `split()`. *Is there a way to perform the split only once from within the comprehension?* I tried what came naturally and it was invalid syntax:

```
>>> [(splt[0],splt[1]) for s in strings with s.split() as splt]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [(splt[0],splt[1]) for s in strings with s.split() as splt]
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you want to use `with`, the object should get methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`. list can not be used here.

Comment: `input` is a builtin, probably not the best idea to use it as a variable

Comment: @gnibbler It wasn't a variable - I used the code block just to give it formatting. I should probably not use the `=` operator though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in this particular case:

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    return [s.split()[:2] for s in strings]
```

Otherwise, though, you can use one generator expression:

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    return [(s[0], s[1]) for s in (s.split() for s in strings)]
```

And if performance is actually critical, just use a function.

Comment: +1 The generator expression seems to be what the question is asking about

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is what I was looking for - too bad I can't accept for another 5 minutes. I guess this gives me time to test it out. I bet nesting these generators will be fun! :)

Comment: +1 It might be better to use `.split(None, 2)` here instead of `.split()` (since we only care about the first two words), just as an aside.

Comment: @arshajii: Yup, that could work — it depends on what needs to be done, though. (`.split(None, 2)` splits into 2 words at most, not the first 2 words.)

Answer (score 4):

Writing what comes to mind naturally from English and hoping it's valid syntax rarely works, unfortunately.

The generalized form of what you're trying to do is bind some expression to a name within a comprehension. There's no direct support to that, but since a `for` clause in a comprehension binds a name to each element from a sequence in turn, you can use `for` over single-element containers to achieve the same effect:

```
>>> strings = ["hello world how are you", "foo bar baz"]
>>> [(splt[0],splt[1]) for s in strings for splt in [s.split()]]
[('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

Comment: It took me a few read-throughs to understand what you meant by "binds a name to each element from a sequence in turn," but once I got that it made a lot of sense to me - thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think using a genexp is nicer, but here's how to do it with a `lambda`. There may be cases when this is a better fit

```
>>> [(lambda splt:(splt[0], splt[1]))(s.split()) for s in input]
[('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

Answer (score 2):

minitech's answer is the right way to do it.

But note that you don't have to do it all in one line, and you don't really gain anything.

This:

```
splits = (s.split() for s in strings)
return [(s[0], s[1]) for s in splits]
```

Does exactly the same thing as this:

```
return [(s[0], s[1]) for s in (s.split() for s in strings)]
```

No extra intermediate values being built, no effect on the garbage collection, just more readability for free.

Also, there's a good chance your real code doesn't actually need a list in the end, just something iterable, in which case you're better off with this:

```
splits = (s.split() for s in strings)
return ((s[0], s[1]) for s in splits)
```

Or, in Python 3.3+:

```
splits = (s.split() for s in strings)
yield from ((s[0], s[1]) for s in splits)
```

---

In fact, an awful lot of programs can be written this way—a series of generator expressions followed by `return`ing/`yield from`ing one last genexpr/listcomp.

Comment: Sometimes my code needs a collection, sometimes an iterable is better - it depends! It's nice to see examples though. (And of course, I know I don't *have* to do anything in one line, I just wanted to see how to accomplish it.)

Comment: @2rs2ts: Remember that you can always turn an iterator into a `list` by calling `list` on it, almost for free, but the other way around costs. (And the point of the "all in one line" thing is that, unlike the case of writing an explicit function or loop, here you don't have to change the flow at all; you can just trivially extract the expression itself to its own line.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    return [s.split()[:2] for s in strings]
```

It uses list splicing. It will return a list of course, but if you want a tuple, you can use:

```
def firstTwoWords(strings):
    return [tuple(s.split()[:2]) for s in strings]
```

Comment: I just gave an elementary example for the sake of the question. I know you could perform the slice in this example, but of course you can't do that for every case.

Comment: @2rs2ts What other cases do you speak of? I'm not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: I don't know, any old thing. Say you're dealing with named tuples which are returned by a function `foo()` and which have `bar`, `baz`, and can have many other parts, depending on the result of calling `foo()` - but you just want `bar` and `baz`, and can't rely on their position in the tuples.

Comment: (Note: if I talked about named tuples incorrectly, I'd just like to let SO know that I don't know anything about named tuples except that I can use dot syntax on them.)

Comment: @2rs2ts: In other words, you know 80% of what there is to know about named tuples. :) Really, that's all there is to it, except for the two different ways to define them and how they work under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

`itemgetter` can be used here. It's a bit more general than `s.split()[:2]`. It allows you to pull arbitrary items out of `s`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> strings = ["hello world how are you", "foo bar baz"]
>>> [itemgetter(0, 1)(s.split()) for s in strings]
[('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

more generally:

```
>>> [itemgetter(1, 2, 0)(s.split()) for s in strings]
[('world', 'how', 'hello'), ('bar', 'baz', 'foo')]
```